# What is the islamic view on sex education or gender studies?

Tags: sex, education

Is sex education allowed in islam.If yes then what is the right age for it.

Answer (score -3):

my suggestion is when the parents feel its the right time or when the child is going through puberty

Comment: Please provide a source for your suggestion, and [edit] it in. As it stand this is not sufficient as a good quality answer.